# UltraTree Binding to Business Object Display Text

Tags: c#, infragistics

I'm binding an `UltraTree` control (version 10.3) to a custom data source, like so:

```
public void Populate(List<FilterDimension> data)
{
    DataBindings.Clear();
    DataSource = data;
    Nodes[0].DataColumnSetResolved.NodeTextColumn = Nodes[0].DataColumnSetResolved.Columns["DisplayText"];
}
```

My expectation is that changing the DisplayText property on any of the bound `FilterDimension` objects will cause the `UltraTree` node's text to update.  In reality, the text in the tree does not update, and the `PropertyChanged` event remains `null` indicating that the `UltraTree` doesn't even listen for this notification.  How do I get the `UltraTree` to listen for property changes in `FilterDimension`?

Here's the relevant code from `FilterDimension`:

```
internal class FilterDimension : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _displayText = null;
    private string _name = null;

    private BindingList<string> _values = new BindingList<string>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the display friendly name.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            FirePropertyChangedNotification("Name");
            if (_displayText == null) { FirePropertyChangedNotification("DisplayText"); }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the display text that is used in TreeView nodes.  When null, uses the Name.
    /// </summary>
    public string DisplayText
    {
        get { return _displayText ?? Name; }
        set { _displayText = value; FirePropertyChangedNotification("DisplayText"); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a read/write list of values.  Is never null.
    /// </summary>
    public BindingList<string> Values
    {
        get { return _values; }
        set { _values = value ?? new BindingList<string>(); }
    }

    #region Events

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void FirePropertyChangedNotification(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that all I needed to do was change to `BindingList<FilterDimension>` instead of `List<FilterDimension`...  I completely missed that the control expects notifications to bubble up from the list.